# Minimize Access, but keep popup form on the screen

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to separate the popup form that I created from Access.

So far:

1. I changed the "Pop up" setting of the form to "Yes".
2. I selected the form as the "Display Form" in the "Current Database" options.
3. I found a function that would minimize Access.

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Global Const SW_HIDE = 0
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Private Declare Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Function fSetAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long)

Dim loX As Long
Dim loForm As Form
On Error Resume Next
Set loForm = Screen.ActiveForm

If Err <> 0 Then
    loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
    Err.Clear
End If

If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loForm.Modal = True Then
    MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " _
      & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
      & "form on screen"
ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loForm.PopUp <> True Then
    MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " _
      & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
      & "form on screen"
Else
    loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
End If
fSetAccessWindow = (loX <> 0)
End Function
```

4. I call that function on Form_Load to open only the form and minimize the Access window.

I noticed that if I open the Access window and then press the "minimize" button it will also minimize the form.

I was wondering if I will be able to separate the two so when I minimize the Access window the form would still remain on the screen?

Comment: I doubt it. However, there is method of hiding the Access app frame and still have forms and reports visible. Common topic.

Comment: The form is a child of the parent application, so minimizing the parent app also minimizes all the child forms. That is by design. It would be better to use something like .NET to create a stand-alone application that uses access as its backend database.

Answer (score 1):

We can hide access instance by keeping form visible. So, write below codes to a standard module.

```
Option Compare Database   
Option Explicit

Global Const SW_HIDE = 0
Global Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Global Const SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Global Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3

Private Declare PtrSafe Function apiShowWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "ShowWindow" (ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long

Function fSetAccessWindow(nCmdShow As Long)
' call fSetAccessWindow(0) for hiding access window
' call fSetAccessWindow(1) for showing access window
' call fSetAccessWindow(2) for minimizing access window
' call fSetAccessWindow(3) for maximizing access window

    Dim loX As Long
    Dim loForm As Form
    On Error Resume Next
    Set loForm = Screen.ActiveForm

    If Err <> 0 Then
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
        Err.Clear
    End If

    If nCmdShow = SW_SHOWMINIMIZED And loForm.Modal = True Then
        MsgBox "Cannot minimize Access with " _
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
        & "form on screen"
    ElseIf nCmdShow = SW_HIDE And loForm.PopUp <> True Then
        MsgBox "Cannot hide Access with " _
        & (loForm.Caption + " ") _
        & "form on screen"
    Else
        loX = apiShowWindow(hWndAccessApp, nCmdShow)
    End If
    fSetAccessWindow = (loX <> 0)
End Function
```

Then call function with proper argument to hide access window. Like-

```
Private Sub CmdHideAccess_Click()
    Call fSetAccessWindow(0)
End Sub
```

Read function comments carefully for more argument if you need.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for your answer. However, I am not sure where should I put the private sub. Tried to search it in Google but no documentation was found for "CmdHideAccess_Click". I would be really grateful if you can give me some link to read more about this function. Thank you in advance!

Comment: First (test purpose) make a form and then take a command button. Then put this line `Call fSetAccessWindow(0)` to ***On Click*** event. If it success then try to put code to form on load event.

Comment: Oh, I am following now. This is what I am currently having. However, this will only minimize Access when the form is being opened. If a user for whatever reason maximize the Access window and click the minimize icon on the Access window this will minimize both the Access and the popup form. I was curious if it is possible to prevent the form being minimized when a user manually minimizes Access. 

PS: As of now I have created an additional button on the form that would minimize Access, but I am not very fond of this solution. I see it more as bodging than an actual solution.